# how to prevent duplicate in database?

Tags: mysql

I need to compare a value typed into a form field against a list queried from a database to ensure duplicate information is not submitted before submit form

Comment: Make the columns `unique` `ALTER TABLE table ADD UNIQUE unique_index(column1, column2, column3);`

Comment: show us what you tryed..

Comment: Step1: Try something.
Step2: Then ask.

Comment: Which programming language is this ? PHP ?

Comment: I am use PHP , HTML and mysql

Answer (score 1):

If you means, checking if user input is already exists in database **BEFORE** submitting it to server ? 
You can send all user input via **AJAX** request, for checking if input already exists, and according to AJAX response to determine if to submit it or not.

IMO, its advice to send it directly to server, and for the server to return a response if the data ***insert successfully*** or ***already exists***.

Note: you can do some input validation, but its up to you.

Hope it help a bit

Answer (score 1):

You may trigger an **ajax call** on '*field change*' and check if you get any resultset for that particular value in database. Alternatively, you may do this right before form submission.

Have a  look at this [tutorial](http://web.enavu.com/tutorials/checking-username-availability-with-ajax-using-jquery/) on checking user availability asynchronously.

Also, you should make the field `unique` in your database table to avoid any accidental duplication.

```
ALTER TABLE TableName ADD UNIQUE (columnName)
```

Hope it helps, cheers!